# How to call a method on every object in a list in parallel in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a list of custom objects and I want to apply a method on each object which alters the internal memory of the objects. I want to be able to do this in parallel without having to return the objects afterwards.

Essentially I would like to have the equivalent of the for(/each) statement below but in parallel.

```py
for env, p, v in zip(envs, policy, value):
    env.step(p, v)
```

Comment: Use lambda functions.

Answer (score 2):

Since pure python does not allow multithreading with really parallel execution due to the global interpreter lock (https://realpython.com/python-gil/), you won't be able to execute your for-loop in parallel without inter-process communication, i.e. returning the object afterwards.

However, as the link says, this might change in the future. Alternatively you could use an alternative Python interpreter.